# about setting new value to variable

Tags: c++, c

(this is also c question)
lets say that i have 2 files, `g1.cpp` , `df.h` (as header).
`df.h` contains variable named `EP1`:

```
#define EP1     400
```

and `g1.cpp` is include `df.h` file.

............................................................

Lets try to set/get EP1 value (by `g1.cpp`)

now if i will try to GET EP1 value it will work without any error:
`int xp = EP1;` (xp = 400)


but when iam trying to SET new value to EP1:
`EP1 = 10000;`

there is an exception:

`error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`
(mingw)

**My Question Is:**
how can i set new value to EP1?

Comment: The only way to change its value is to change its definition and recompile your program. If you wanted to be able to change its value at run time, *you shouldn't have defined it as a macro*.

Comment: Backwards how write everything you do? Variables are set to new values, values aren't set to new variables.  xp is a variable, 400 is a value ... you're trying to set 400 to 10000.

Answer (score 4):

A macro is not a variable. When compiling, macros transform your code at an early stage such that a code that looks like this:

```
#define EP1 4000
int xp = EP1;
EP1 = 30;
```

Is transformed into:

```
int xp = 4000;
4000 = 30;
```

And I hope that it is obvious why the second assignment makes no sense (and produces the error that you see).

It sounds like you want to use a variable.

Comment: i can change the type of the declaration (global)?

Comment: I'm sorry jhon, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: You can change the value of a macro.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yeah. Although I doubt that a macro is at all helpful for Jhon. I've reworded things.

Comment: lets say that i will change the declaration type of EP1 to : extern int EP1; (global) and will include this h file in cpp files i will be able to set the value of EP1 from cpp those cpp files?

Comment: @jhon Yes, you can do that, *if* if you define EP1 somewhere with `int EP1;` (that should go into one of your cpp files, not a header file).

Answer (score 4):

> My Question Is: how can i set new value to EP1?

```
#undef EP1
#define EP1 10000
```

`EP1` is not a variable, it is a [macro](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/).

Answer (score 1):

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        int i = VAL; //VAL is the macro defined in the header file
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
        #undef VAL   
        #define VAL 1000 //defining the macro with a new value
        i = VAL;
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make EP1 == 10000 (or whatever number you please to change it to)

```
#undef EP1
#define EP1 10000 // or some other value
```

By the way, why isn't EP1 defined as a variable?

```
int EP1 = 40000;
```

You can define in as a global in your header file:

```
extern int EP1;
```

Comment: Ivalue requires left operand, ( I've never seen this error in mingw but I think it's trying to mix match, if that doesn't work then change the macro to a simple variable declaration xD yes jhon I was joking

Comment: @jhon you obviously have more to learn before you should be seeking help by posting questions here. Consult a textbook please.